Github Action _ Overwriting/replace/update .json file prblem
I want to use google web API to crap some coffee shop info from my country
then there is already a original version .json file in my repo to use, but if some new coffee shop be created ,I need to update my {data.json} to latest version by myself , so I want use GitHub Action to automated update this change.
How could I do?

set up cron to time my {data.json} update(like one month/week)


set a web crawler.js (already done) > output data as .json file


when let crawler run on action, I can get {data.json} output, right?(if not please tell me)
next ,how to replace/Overwriting/update my original version {data.json} after got this output
(Step here stock me)use what action that I can complete this step


next,{data.json} will affect to my scss but it's ok (already find scss build action but try it yet)


all thing done >>and deploy automated(this is not problem for me)

sorry to read my poor english and thx to answer my question
now only write a crawler , set Action yet
need json file output when it work on GitHub Action
auto overwriting/replace/update original json file
rebuild the scss
auto deploy
only need how to do step3 ,I can search other step by myself but I can't find step3's action or I don't understand how it work
